# argument not work on expect through command line

Tags: expect, ansible

Here I have creating script which execute the `ansible-playbook`, After the execute script which ask the `Sudo password` which one I have to send(*sudo password*) though `expect` and `send` but getting below error:

Script :

```
$ cat changedns

#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ansible-playbook -i "$1," /home/admin/ansible/test.yml -K 
match_max 100000
expect "SUDO password:"
send -- "admin@123\r"
send -- "\r"
expect eof
```

Output:

```
$ ./changedns bn
can't read "1": no such variable
    while executing
"spawn ansible-playbook -i "$1," /home/adminto/ansible/test.yml -K "
    (file "./changedns" line 2)
```

Anyone have idea how to deal with this ?

Comment: 1) That's an `expect` script, not a shell script; 2) You appear to have an extra newline at the start, which likely makes it into a shell script (if you spawn it from a shell), except that 3) those are tcl errors so it is running expect regardless.

Comment: You can't reference command line arguments like that in an expect script: see for example [How to pass argument in expect through command line in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17060172/4440445)